# Unable to run Websphere MQ application once deployed

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

Good day. I have developed an application which works successfully on my local machine but I have run into a problem when moving out to production.

The error is as follows:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'IBM.XMS.Admin, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d2666ab12fca862b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'IBM.XMS.Admin, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d2666ab12fca862b'

I understand where this file is - C:\Prog... - and my .Net application is simply referencing IBM.XMS.dll which works. It's when I deploy and run I get the error above.

I used the following installation instructions and restarted the system too:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzav.doc/un10290_.htm

Comment: According to that link it sounds like the assemblies are installed to the GAC.  You installed them into the GAC on the production machine as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is built with XMS v2.5. Do you have XMS v2.5 (shipped with MQ v7.5 client) installed on the other machine?

Answer (score 0):

check out Microsoft's [fusion log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) and see how you get on.

In my experience when I see this message the keywords are *or one of its dependencies*. The fusion log may help you find out which one.